# Keep all divs in the same position

Tags: html, css

I want to position social buttons below the string in the same position, actually before the border. `position: absolute;` not working correctly.

**Codepen** http://codepen.io/panakour/pen/GZegaB

**Expected behaviour** [image]

Comment: What is the expected behaviour? Could you present some kind of draft?

Comment: Do you want to keep the social icons on the bottom?

Comment: Yes, I want to keep the social buttons at the bottom, before close border

Comment: On the bottom of the page? I don't understand. Can you please post a screenshot with the wanted behaviour?

Comment: I've updated my answer

Comment: Can you place the `div.social-media-row` before or after the `div.row`?

Comment: Well, I updated my answer. Hope this helps!

Comment: You need to include the relevant markup here. Links to code can disappear or change tomorrow making your question useless to future visitors.

Comment: Adding to Rob's point - since your HTML appears very long, it'd be a good idea to trim it down to a [mcve] before posting your code here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please move the `div.social-media-row` after `div.row`:

[image]

Then you have to set `div.business-content` to `position: relative`.

After that align the social buttons at the bottom of the `business-content`:

```
div.social-media-row {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

I've also forked your pen and modded the code. Just look at the first example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Myxwjy

Comment: Doing this the social icons won't be aligned to the bottom border, since the bussiness-body depend on text height

Comment: @IvanRodriguezTorres: What do you mean? This works for sure.

Comment: #roNn23 Thank you for answer. What I want to do is to align the buttons to the bottom border, like  #Ivan say

Comment: @roNn23 sorry, I haven't seen the first element. I checked one random. And yes, it works, you were right!!

Comment: @Panagiotis: Please update your question, like recommended and please accept my answer, if it helps you.

Comment: @roNn23 Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

First, Move the DIV `.social-media-row` out of its parent container to the bottom of the `.row` DIV

Then add `position: relative;` to `.row`, and in the CSS rule for `.social-media-row` change `top: 317px;` to `bottom: 0px;`

Codepen here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WwmQWM

( I have only changed it for the first appearance - you have to change it in all the others too)